# file format issue when using HTTP POST via C# to upload a picture file

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest

SDO REST API - The issue is that when I upload the file, it has no format and it looks like this: 98A9799C-CFB1-423B-A4AD-40609282F861 (2.7 MB) DELETE <--- this file needs to be picture.jpg

The file is simply picture.jpg

```
public string POST(string URI, string file)
        {
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
            credentials.UserName = AppVars.Username;
            credentials.Password = AppVars.Password;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
            request.Credentials = credentials;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //I have also tried request.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; and ran into the same issue.

            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            Stream os = null;
            try
            { 
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   
                os = request.GetRequestStream();
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (os != null)
                {
                    os.Close();
                }
            }
            try
            { 
                WebResponse requestResponse = request.GetResponse();
                if (requestResponse == null)
                { return null; }
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(requestResponse.GetResponseStream());
                return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a cache issue. I cleared my browser cache and I was able to view the image online.